# How to check a python 2 script for errors without execution

Tags: python, python-2.7, compilation, interpreter

Is there a way to check whether a ***python 2*** script has any errors ?

I need to check it using terminal!

For python 3 I found

```
python3 -m py_compile source.py
```

and

```
python3 -m compileall source.py
```

and catching the result in a file will do the thing.

and it works just fine from terminal, but not with python 2.

I've Python 2.7.15rc1 installed.

Comment: Why do you assume, `python3 -m ..` will work with files you wrote using `python 2`. Did you search the internet? Seems to me, a google search of `How to compile Python 2 vs. Python 3` would do the trick.

Comment: @abhishek I did not assume that. I only mentioned it to say that it does not work with python 2 in case of someone thinks about it as a solution.

Comment: Run `python -m compileall yourpython2file.py` and tell me what you get

Comment: @abhishek I got nothing, and it produces result.pyc even if the script has errors.
Also "echo $?" in terminal prints 0.